# How do I get the desired result?

Tags: mysql

Need help on mysql statement

```
P_ID |  P_NAME 

1   P1
2   P2



PT_ID | P_ID | S_ID
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
1   2   1
1   2   2
1   2   3
1   2   4
```

Required Result:

```
P_ID | P_NAME | S_ID    
1   P1  3
2   P2  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select t1.P_ID, t1.P_Name, count(t2.SID) as S_ID
     FROM table1 t1 join table t2 on t1.P_ID = t2.P_ID
          Group by t2.P_ID
```

Comment: This is working. Sorry bt desired answer was different .. Forgot to maention.. i need full row of second table

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT tab1.P_ID,
       P_NAME,
       S_ID
  FROM tab1 
  JOIN tab2
    ON tab1.p_id = tab2.p_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.P_ID,
    Table1.P_NAME,
    MAX(Table2.S_ID) AS S_ID
FROM
    Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.P_ID=Table2.P_ID
GROUP BY
    Table1.P_ID,
    Table1.P_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN like

```
SELECT T1.P_ID, T1.P_NAME, MAX(T2.S_ID) AS S_ID
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.P_ID=T2.P_ID
GROUP BY T1.P_ID, T1.P_NAME
```